# Injected script is unable to declare variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to inject some JS into a webpage using my Chrome extension's content script. The injected script declares a variable, which prints okay when printed from the same injected script. However, if I try to access the same variable later in the page or even in the console, it is not found. Please note that I am not declaring the variable in my content script, I am injecting JS in the actual webpage.

Here is the minimal code from content script:

```
var script = `<script>
              var zzxx = "random stuff";
              console.log(zzxx);
              window.xyz = "1234";
              console.log(window.xyz);
              </script>`;

$('body').append(script);
```

Output:

```
random stuff
1234
```

But cannot access zzxx or window.xyz from console or another injected script. What's the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it should be an issue with variable range

To be sure try to replace

```
var zzxx = "random stuff";
```

with :

```
window.zzxx = "random stuff"
```

**Edit this work for me :**

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.innerHTML = "var toto = 3; console.log(toto);";
$("head").append(s);
```

Comment: As I am getting the printed message on console (see the ouput part in question), it suggests that script was executed. I have also tried window.xyz (see the code in question)

Comment: I believe it will not work, but what if you try to access your variable injecting a new script?

Comment: That's what I was originally trying. Inject variable through one script and access through the other. Doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that the body of the page is not reloaded dynamically? (erasing your script)

Comment: I can still see the script in the DOM using inspector of chrome

Comment: I injected your script in google.de, it prints but still cannot access 'toto', it says variable not defined